# What does "offset" mean in Angular Auth OIDC config values?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

In my project, there is a configuration value for Oauth that I do not understand:

```
  auth: {
        maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds: 600        
    },
```

Based on the document I am reading: https://nice-hill-002425310.azurestaticapps.net/docs/documentation/configuration

For `maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds` It says:

> The amount of offset allowed between the server creating the token, and the client app receiving the id_token.

What does the offset mean in this case? Is it like a timing unit? 
I am assuming it means that each user can only receive one token every 600 seconds?

Can someone explains what does the offset mean? and what `maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds` is doing to the token?

Answer (score 1):

The docs you linked to are specifically for the angular-auth-oidc-client library so hopefully that's what you're using. In that case the `maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds` is being used to determine how much clock skew is allowed between the issuing server and the consuming browser. In this case, 600 seconds would mean the clocks can be 10 minutes different from one another and the token will still be considered valid.

However, today I came across this issue and any value I pushed in higher than 299 was causing my token to be considered expired. I looked back through the changelog and found a recent-ish PR that added this check and a new configuration value that allows you to ignore it (disableIdTokenValidation).